# What is the best regex instead of this code?

Tags: c#, regex, contains

Regex for me is chinese. I prefer to write this code. 
Yet if I want to replace this code with regex, what is the best regex match for it?

```
        if (strValue.Contains(",") || strValue.Contains("-") || strValue.Contains("+") || strValue.Contains(".") || strValue.Contains("!") ||                    
                strValue.Contains("@") || strValue.Contains("#") || strValue.Contains("$") || strValue.Contains("%") || strValue.Contains("*") ||                    
                strValue.Contains("(") || strValue.Contains(")") || strValue.Contains("}") || strValue.Contains("{") || strValue.Contains("`") ||
                strValue.Contains("\"") || strValue.Contains("^") || strValue.Contains("&") || strValue.Contains("[") || strValue.Contains("]") ||
                strValue.Contains("=") || strValue.Contains("+") || strValue.Contains("!") || strValue.Contains(";") || strValue.Contains(":") || 
                strValue.Contains("|"))
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: It would also help to understand what this code is trying to achieve. People can see it will return false if certain characters are found, but are you validating URLs or something with this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looking up RegEx tutorials to learn how to do it? If so at what part did you get stuck?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Surely if he just wants to replace that code then it doesn't matter what it is being run against... Anything else I would imagine to be out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Chris It matters to help alleviate XY Problems and it is always nice to understand where and how code is used. Like I said, people can see what the code is doing, but not why.

Comment: Coding is just problem solving.  Your approach to solving this problem  is "I know what I want, but I don't want to make an effort."  To me, that's unacceptable.

Comment: I've edited your question, I hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: I found a more appropriate way to tackle this issue. .Net offers this function (Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()): if (strValue.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1) { return false; } Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

A regex matching your criteria would be:

```
@"[,+.!@#$%*()}{`\\^&[\]=+!;:|-]"
```

`[...]` denotes a character class. *Any character* inside this class will match the output.

`-` has to go first or last (or has to be escaped), because regex allow you to specify ranges in the form of `[a-z]`

Comment: would the `-` definitely not get used as a range operator there?

Comment: @Chris: well spotted. I've moved it to the end of the character class.

Comment: Its bitten me enough times that I always look out for that now and put it at the beginning or end. I usually opt for beginning though, I must admit. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^[^,\-\.!@#\$%\(\)\{\}`\\\^&\[\]=!;:|+\*]+$
```

http://rubular.com/r/EfsarXwG8I

If your string matches this regex, then it's good.

It's really not complicated:

```
`^`            start of string
`[^....]`      match all characters NOT inside this class
`+`            match one of more (use * instead if you want to pass empty strings)
`$`            end of string
```

All the stuff between the square brackets (other than the first `^`) is the list of characters you want to reject with the added wrinkle that some of them need escaping (with `\`) because they have special meaning in the regex language.

Edit: actually, I probably overdid it with the escaping, I *think* only `-`, `[`, `]` and `\` need escaping, but it doesn't seem to hurt to be over cautious in this case.

Comment: "It's really not complicated" - I think for him `^[^,\-\.!@#\$%\(\)\{\}\\\^&\[\]=!;:|+\*]+$` is what he refered to as chinese ;-)

Comment: @BlueM: I understand that, but while at first glance it's ugly and some (okay, a lot of) regex can end up horribly hard to read (it's a *write only* language), this one really isn't complicated. It's just *don't match any of these*.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the short answer would be something along these lines:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[\,\-\+\.\!\@\#\$\%\*\(\)\{\}\`]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success) {
    return false;
}
```

However, I am almost certain that the approach of choosing "an arbitrary list of punctuation marks to exclude" is probably the wrong approach.  Are you only wanting to allow a set of numbers, characters, and (possibly) underscore?  If so, I would search only for the characters you WANT rather than a list of characters that you *think* you don't want.  (What if the input contains a Hindi characters ((हिन्दी) for example?)  Your example AND the associated regular expression are going to allow these characters - and you probably don't want them to.

Comment: Your regex will only match a string which contains all characters in this particular order. You are missing a character class.

Comment: You are correct knitti.  I'll update

Comment: thanks BlueM.  Spotted it but didn't correct until you also spotted it!

Comment: Your expression is missing several characters from the question (e.g; `=` and `\ `).

Comment: OK.  I'm not going to update the regexp again.  I am aware that some of the characters are missing. The POINT about my answer was to reconsider the approach of the OP i.e. consider ensuring that only PERMISSIBLE characters are included rather than an ARBITRARY list of characters there are not permissible.

Comment: @Chris Walsh
I agree. What is the better approach?

Comment: @Chris
I found a more appropriate way to tackle this issue. 
.Net offers this function (Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()):             

if (strValue.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1)
            {                
                return false;
            }

Thanks all.

Comment: That's a much better solution.  We can now see that the filtering is related to filename/filepaths and you are using standard library functions to provide (im)permissible characters.  The code should work across different OSs also which have different invalid characters.